# how to prevent a user from entering exactly the same information in SQL

Tags: php, mysql

How do I trap an entry with different information from becoming a duplicate in my SQL?
For example.

I have in my DB these info.

```
January 1, 2017, New Year, Nationwide.
```

I want to enter another holiday in the same exact date but in a local place.

How do I do that?

Comment: Look up `UNIQUE` index constraints.

Comment: composite key is suggested on `date` and `location`. you can also include `holiday` if required.

Comment: i only want the row to be unique. not the column.

Comment: Hire a decent, professional and skilled coder.

Comment: because what if i want enter a different holiday with the same date. So i guess unique constraints wont work on this one.

Comment: @MilchePatern Sir i want to learn to code myself. Im a beginner at this.

Answer (score 0):

Your constraint seems too wide (something like `UNIQUE (day,year)`), you should set your table constraint to `UNIQUE (day,year,description,location)` to be able to add an entry with just a location change.

Comment: does that constraint means a UNIQUE ROW of (Date,description,location) ? Cause if not. Thats not what i need.

Comment: It is not a problem with your code, the change is to be done on the database side.

Answer (score 0):

```
$chkentry="select `HDDATE`,`HDLOCATION`,`HOLIDAYNAME` from rfc_bio_holiday_m where HDDATE='$hddate' and HDLOCATION ='$hdlocation'  and HOLIDAYNAME='$holidayname' HDSTATUS=1";  
                    if ($result=$conn->query($chkentry)) 
                    {   while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                        list($entryexist) = $row;  

                        }   
                    }


            if  ($entryexist>0) #Condition after this
```

THIS IS MY CODE

Comment: this code has an error of "undefined variable entryexist